# Spring Security Oauth2, app behavior with session disabled

Tags: session, spring-security, session-cookies, spring-security-oauth2, spring-session

I disabled the session management in my REST service, because I am using Oauth2 to authenticate clients + users. So I have these configurations :

Resource server

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override 
  public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS );
    //....
  }
}
```

And the basic authentication :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityWebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override 
  public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS );
    //....
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's relevant to do that in the both configurations.

Now when I send a request to a protected path with an authenticated client (including the access token). The response headers contain a `JSESSIONID`something like

`set-cookie:JSESSIONID=A3E6E26C28916C5D95795E934F15C8F1`
Is it a normal behavior?

To go further with my tests, I did this (to get current connected user):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping( "/protected" )
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ChicoweursToUIController {

    private UIService service;

    @GetMapping
    public UserDTO findUser( OAuth2Authentication authentication, HttpSession session ) {
       log.info( "Connected user: {}", authentication.getUserAuthentication().getName() );
       log.info( "Is session null: {}", session==null );
       return service.findUser(authentication.getUserAuthentication().getName()  );
    }
}
```

The log results are :

```
Connected user: username@mail.com
Is session null: false
```

So why the `HttpSession` is not null?

In my mind, I thaught that the Spring Security Context relies on the session to get the authenticated user, i-e if the session is disabled, the security context can't find the current user. Am I wrong? Could someone clarify me these points please?

And finally, can I **ALWAYS** rely on the `OAuth2Authentication` to find the current connected client and user even the session is disabled?

Thanks a lot

Comment: [This](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4242)  and [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4717#issuecomment-340115893) should answer some of your questions

Comment: Thank you @Vasan but it is not clear at all.